# Binary Search seems superior, why did the committee of C++ still have Find in the algorithm library?

Tags: c++, algorithms, complexity, search, big-o

I wish to search for an integer in a vector of integer. I have two candidates for the job:

1. [Binary Search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/)
2. [Find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

It seems that **Binary Search** is the best candidate for the job as although I have to sort the vector, the total running time will be `O(NLog2N)` assuming quicksort take `O(NLog2N)` and searching takes `O(Log2N)`.

The running time for **Find** will be `O(N)`.

It seems such clear cut that **Binary Search** is superior to **Find**, why did the committee of C++ still have Find in the algorithm library?

I am sure the C++ committee had their reasons for including **Find**, what benefits of **Find** am I missing or how is **Find** superior to **Binary Search**?

EDITED : Changed running time of quicksort to NLog2N

Comment: -1, you changed your wrong statement about the running time of quicksort by an edit, which obviously makes your assumption pointless that "Binary Search is superior to Find". Honestly, when I would have noticed such an error in a question of mine, I would immediately retract the question.

Comment: @DocBrown worth noting that asker of the question has no way to "retract" it when it has got upvoted answers - and this is just the case here, starting with the [fastest gun kind one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/228295/31260) that merely qualifies as a comment

Comment: @DocBrown Yea I have no way to retract the question once an answer has been given , anyway my question is still valid as NlogN is quicker than N , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962545/on-log-n-complexity-similar-to-linear , I believe i dont deserve the downvote

Comment: @Computernerd: You misunderstood the answers to that linked SO question. An O(NlogN) algorithm can be faster than an O(N) one, but that all depends on the constants and non-dominant factors that are ignored by Big-O notation. In this case, the "sort+binary search" will most likely loose out to the linear search unless you are searching a lot on the same sorted sequence.

Comment: @Computernerd: N*(log N) is larger than N for N beeing sufficiently large (since log N is larger than 1 for N beeing larger than the base of the logarithm). Nevertheless an "O(NlogN)" algorithm can be faster than an O(N) algorithm in some special cases, but don't expect a one-short Quick-Sort + Binary Search to be faster than a "Find" for any real-world library implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Not every list is sorted, yet sometimes there are things we'd like to find.

Also quicksort is `O(n log n)`, which means it takes longer than `O(n)`.

Comment: @ U2ZEF1 not really , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962545/on-log-n-complexity-similar-to-linear

Comment: No, quicksort is not O(n log n), it is O(n^2)! O(n log n) is the average complexity of quicksort (in number of comparisons).

Comment: @fish Sure. There's still no way it's beating linear `find`. The confusion stems from the (now edited) question stating quicksort was `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that from a theoretical perspective it's impossible to let sorting and finding be quicker than finding. To sort, you need to look at every element at least once to determine its place. To find, in the worst case scenario, you need to look at every element once (provided they are not sorted). Only when you're doing repeated searches, it may make sense to sort the elements first (a "startup fee") to have "cheaper" searches after that.

Comment: Even better, if it's common for your sought-after element to exist, linear `find` will only look at half the list on average. Sorting still has to look at everything.

Comment: @U2EF1 Only under certain conditions (e.g. random distribution of the elements). Anyway, such details are not very important for the theoretical argument I wanted to make. :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, binary search provides you with a high performance solution when your data is sorted, while find is slower but does not have that presorted constraint.

In addition it is important to note that to sort a vector you must either copy it and mutate it or simply mutate it. This is not only expensive but has side effects which may not match the semantics of your algorithm.

Additionally C++11 defines the new collections std::unordered_set and std::unordered_map which are by definition not compatible with binary search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Find is meant to operate on any generic STL container, some of which are expensive to sort. There are faster ways to find an item with the right data structure, such as with `std::set`, and that class has a `find` member function.

Furthermore, the premise of your question is false. The asymptotic complexity of quicksort is O(n^2), not O(log 2n) or O(n log n). Many people seem to confuse that with the average complexity of [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

> Quicksort, or partition-exchange sort, is a sorting algorithm
>   developed by Tony Hoare that, on average, makes O(n log n) comparisons
>   to sort n items. **In the worst case, it makes O(n^2) comparisons**, though
>   this behavior is rare.

Comment: The asymptotic complexity of quicksort *is* Θ(n log n) ... in the average case. The asymptotic complexity of quicksort *is* Θ(n²) ... in the worst case. Both statements are correct and important, and generally both bounds should be given. It's silly to claim one case is *the* case that matters and the other should, if mentioned at all, be hidden behind further qualification. There is no distinction between "average complexity" and "asymptotic complexity", that wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: @delnan Asymptotic complexity talks about worst case complexity, unless stated otherwise, and that is what Big-O is, function that is an upper bound to another (again, look it up if you don't believe me). The average case complexity of quicksort is O(n log n). You are using theta instead of omicron, which means a different thing: tight bounds, both upper and lower.

Comment: Can you give a citation? Asymptotic complexity just means the limit of some function as n -> infinity. That function can be the time taken or number of operations in the worst case (and this is indeed the most common, so this is sometimes left unstated). But other important (sometimes more important) measures are the time taken in the average case, the space used in the worst case, the space used in the average case, or the count of a *certain* operation (e.g. the comparison in functions). And the theta vs. omicron thing is completely orthogonal: ...

Comment: ... It expresses *how* you bound the function in question, not which function you bound. For example, you can say the worst-case time of linear search is in O(n³) because it's asymptotically less than c*n³, but a more precise bound would be O(n), and an even more precise one would be Θ(n), which *also* states that it isn't actually better than linear. Big Oh is often (misleadingly) used when we have tight bounds, but it's also useful when you haven't figured out the exact bound yet or can't be bothered to ("the worst-case time complexity is at most linear, maybe better").

Comment: @delnan citation: "A further tacit assumption is that the worst case analysis of computational complexity is in question unless stated otherwise" [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity)

Comment: That's a reason to object to "*The* complexity is O(...)" used to mean the average case, but not a reason to sow further confusion. In the face of confusion about which case should be used, it is fully correct, and I would argue much clearer, to simply drop the notion of a "default" case and explicitly distinguish the various cases. Aside from that, your use of other terminology (as details in previous comments) is IMHO worse than an unconvential default. You are mostly nitpicking, and not even correctly at that.

Comment: @delnan I honestly did not mean to nitpick; I think it is a very important distinction that we are talking about average case, not worst case. The premise of the question is false because of this. If the OP used the correct worst-case complexity, the question would have answered itself. Also, please do point out my mistakes in other comments, I do not take it personally. This is just a website where I spend some of my free time, after all. On the same note, I apologize if I happened to offend you in any way, reading back I can see how I might have come off  stuck-up.

Comment: No offense taken. I absolutely agree that it's an important distinction, I am objecting to how you point that out: Your previous writings reads as if the average case was a fringe case that is much less important and should, if at all, be mentioned in fine print. As for the question resolving itself: The question also answers itself if the O(n log n) bound is used, but OP initially claimed that quicksort was O(log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what was mentioned, even given an array that was already sorted, if it has, say, just a measly 10 elements in it, the linear-time search is likely to strongly outperform the logarithmic-time binary search. Algorithmic complexity doesn't equate to speed. It describes scalability, but scalability isn't so useful on inputs that don't scale.

Besides that a binary search is less generalized and less applicable, since it requires random-access iterators which linked structures generally can't provide. A sequential search only requires forward iterators which practically any data structure can provide.